# Where will the data go after delete from memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

Where does the **PERMANENTLY DELETED DATA** go from memory? And where will the data go after clicking shift+delete keys.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows? Do you mean files deleted from the Recycle Bin?

Comment: Check this ---> https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-delete-shift+delete-shredding-and-rm

Comment: yes this is about windows....@cad

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the concept of File System first. When you press shift+delete, OS calls File System routine to delete file from entry table. File System could either chose to just remove the entry (mark file as deleted) or zero out data of the file and then remove permanently from entry table.
In case of shift+delete, File System assure you to delete file permanently i.e. zero out data and remove entry from the directory table. In that case it is not recoverable. Although some hardware hacks are possible to recover data, by analyzing magnetic fingerprints of hard disk.
If you delete file simply by pressing delete key; It actually just mark file as deleted in file system entry, thus file system could use It's data sector and overwrite with other content. In this case file is recoverable but not guaranteed to be 100%, File System could have corrupted it by overwriting It's data sector.